# How do I find which serial I used for Photoshop CS5 on my computer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, product-key, photoshop-cs5

I want to move my Photoshop CS5 installation to a new computer.
Unfortunately, I lost the paper with the cd-key.

Is there a way to recover the serial from my local installation?

Comment: Perhaps Help=>About?

Comment: @terdon - unfortunately, not.

Comment: If you logged in with your Adobe account when you first used the serial number, I believe it gets tied to your Adobe account and is retrievable through their website. (I'm not entirely sure though, this is how it worked for older CS versions at least).

Comment: @Rain - indeed, I can find it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you logged in with your Adobe account when you first used the serial number, I believe it gets tied to your Adobe account and is retrievable through their website.

Answer (score 6):

Use a regedit reader specialized for license keys,for example :

[LicenseCrawler](http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler_download.htm) (free, portable)

or

[The Magical Jellybean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) (has free version)

Comment: This program can help also. http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Comment: LicenseCrawler did not find it in my case, but that Belarc Advisor worked

Answer (score 5):

Go into system information under help in the photoshop application. A long list of things will come up stuff like your plug-ins ect.

Among that will be the serial number without the dashes -  just put a dash every four numbers and that is your serial number that you used to install the program.

Comment: This only shows 5 blocks of 4 digits; Adobe CS5 uses a serial number with 6 blocks of 4 digits.

Answer (score 3):

The serial number in system info may get you only 5 blocks of 4 digits where the complete serial number may be 6 blocks of 4 digits. Belarc Advisor gets the comlete 6 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

A Mac option that worked for (my old but highly functional) Photoshop CS 5.1, just opened a terminal and ran

`find /Library/Application\ Support/ -name 'regid*.swidtag' -exec cat {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

In any recent version of Adobe Photoshop:

`Help` > `System Info...`

Find the following strings there:

```
License Type: Subscription Volume License
Serial number: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

The last one is a serial number you find.